# jquery spservices update listitem

Tags: jquery, listitem, spservices

i'm trying to update a listitem using jquery spservices. everything is working but when i try to add a href to a richtextfield it doesnt work. it only updates plain text not the href.
below is code, it's just a test so those urls are for testing.

```
function fn_UpdateListItem(){
$().SPServices({
operation: 'UpdateListItems',
listName: 'Bedrijven',
ID: 1,
valuepairs: [["Software", "<a href='http://www.google.nl'>its a test.</a>"]],
completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
alert('test complete');
}
});
}
```

if i change the valuepairs to

```
valuepairs: [[\"Software\", \"test\"]],
```

it works it puts test in the rich text field. but with href it doesnt work. anyone knows how to fix ? thanks in advane

Comment: Why do you have a backslash before your double quotes? Also, when you say it doesn't update the href, do you mean just the href attribute, or the entire anchor tag? And when you say it "doesn't work", do you mean the value isn't changed at all, or you see the anchor tag as text instead of an html anchor tag?

Comment: had that because i tried everything. i found it on the internet and tried it, but didnt work. about the href: the field is just empty. it doesnt put any value in it. but when i dont use a href is does.the problem is i need to update it with a href.

Comment: I think you mean you need to update the field with an `<a>` or an `anchor` or even a "link". `href` is just an attribute of the anchor tag. Sorry if it seems like I'm nitpicking, but it makes it unclear what you are actually asking for. If you manually update the field with the `<a>`, does it work like it should? Here is a post that suggests you can't edit the HTML of a rich text field, and need to use "enhanced" instead: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17269/how-do-i-edit-the-html-source-of-a-rich-text-column

Comment: thanks for the reply, i mean a link like: <a href='www.google.nl'> (its just a example. but when i put it in the field its empty. if i just put plain text in it it works. the field type is enhanced rich textifled.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem for Sharepoint 2010, in this case the 
***var dfNotes = CKEDITOR.instances.notes.getData();*** didn't work for me, i found this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee658527(v=office.14).aspx

```
var value = SP.Utilities.HttpUtility.htmlEncode(html);
```

> Edit
>
> Tested on **Sharepoint 2016 SharePoint On-Premises**, It works too, so i it should work for **SharePoint Online** aswell !!

This is how it worked for me:

```
function AddListItem(html, list) { 
    var value = SP.Utilities.HttpUtility.htmlEncode(html);        
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        async: false,
        batchCmd: "New",
        listName: list,
        valuepairs: [["Title", 'Title'], ["Content", value]],
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            console.log(Status);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the actual solution.  Prior to submitting to a SharePoint list, the HTML-ized data are stored in XML, which doesn't take kindly to embedded HTML tags, so they need to be escaped.  Thanks to [feedback](https://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/528193) on the SPServices forum, I was able to determine this was the case in my example above.

I revised my code to look like this:

```
var dfNotes = CKEDITOR.instances.notes.getData();

$().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    async: false,
    batchCmd: "Update",
    listName: list,
    ID: prog,
    valuepairs: [["Notes", $("#notes").text(dfNotes).html()]],
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        alert($("#notes").html());
    }
});
```

The first line references a rich text editor field that contains newly modified text. Note the slight difference in the `valuepairs` line where it now uses `.text().html()` to escape the text for transmission via XML.

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

You need encode the html code (replace the characters < and > for JavaScript: Escaping Special Characters, `&lt;` and `&gt;`; [this is an example of some characters](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/)), this way you going to have a string available to save in the rich content text field (Notes), when The item is updated your data going to have a html code.

This is the code:

```
function fn_UpdateListItem(){

    var link = htmlEscape('<a href='http://www.google.nl'>its a test.</a>');

    $().SPServices({
        operation: 'UpdateListItems',
        listName: 'Bedrijven',
        ID: 1,
        valuepairs: [["Software", link]],
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            alert('test complete');
        }
     });
}

//This function makes the magic
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

Best regards